# curl and file_get_contents not working for specific site (tried user agent)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I wanted to get the content of a specific url using php, so I tried both file_get_content and curl, but both returned an empty string.

Below are the code I used for the two functions.

For curl,

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>  true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.jjwxc.net/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT   =>  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://google.com",
    CURLOPT_HEADER  =>  TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  =>  TRUE
));
$page = h(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

For file_get_content,

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http'  =>  [
        'user_agent'    =>  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36'
    ]
]);
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.jjwxc.net/', false, $context);
```

Both codes are able to produce results for other sites, such as www.google.com.

I was able to open the webpage through browser, get content through command line curl, and through python requests.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: Both your sample pieces of code appear to work fine (provided I remove the call  to whatever the h() function is in the first sample), echo'ing out `$page` shows the source of the page you're pulling content from.

Comment: check the php error log and `echo curl_error($curl);`

Comment: @Vex Sorry for the h(), this is actually a cakephp function I forgot to remove. Thanks for you information, I tried setting up a test page outside cakephp, it dumps out the response :) So I guess it is actually a cakephp problem, I am finally one step closer to the solution!

Comment: @Deadooshka, I check the error log, but nothing turned up. cuel_error($curl) doesn't turn up anything either.

Comment: Now I can get `curl` to display the right encoding with a little bit of `iconv`, still no luck get with `file_get_contents`, the encoding is all messed up.

Comment: Finally figured out the problem, there is gzip with file_get_contens, so I need to unzip before processing.